# PyLucene error with IceTea / JDK / JRE

Tags: java, python, lucene, pylucene

I have followed the installation instructionrs http://bendemott.blogspot.de/2013/11/installing-pylucene-4-451.html for pylucene using the latest `pylucene-4.9.0.0`.

And when i tried to to `lucene.initVM()`, I get the following error:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lucene
>>> lucene.initVM()
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ffba22808b8, pid=5189, tid=140718811092800
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b32) (build 1.7.0_65-b32)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea 2.5.3
# Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, package 7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x6088b8]  jni_RegisterNatives+0x58
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/alvas/hs_err_pid5189.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions on how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And the file http://pastebin.com/6B8FyC4Z

**Is there something wrong with my IceTea configuration? or my JDK? or JRE?**

**How should I resolve the problem?**

Comment: I think you should pass some more info about architecture of your pc and software installation. Python is 64 bit? Java is 64 bit. If python is not, I fear that there can be issues. I read "mixed mode linux-amd64 ".

Comment: Did you try the JDK 8?

Comment: I end up reinstalling on a fresh server and it works but there's still no clue on what went wrong =(

Answer (score 1):

So I took a look at your stack trace, and I don't think the issue was specifically pyLucene. In the stack trace, you see this error:

```
siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000
```

If you look at the first part, SIGSEGV, that means you have a segmentation fault somewhere in your system. SEGV_MAPERR is the specific error, which means that OpenJDK was trying to map memory to an object and failed. This could've been caused by not enough memory, a bad pagefile/virtual memory, bad address space, or even a bad library. Why it worked on another machine could be anything. Core dumps are really useful, so if you can run

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

that will help give you something to look at. Was this in a VM or on a physical machine? I've seen random sigsegv in my Ubuntu VMs if they don't have enough memory allocated for various Java tasks. I saw this on my ESXi hypervisors specifically, and I noticed it the most was when ESXi started to perform memory swapping. I was able to resolve this by increasing memory, rebooting the VM, and making sure my hypervisor wasn't swapping memory. Let me know if that helps. :)

Edit: I also noticed that if the underlying storage provider had poor performance, that would impact with swap data and I feel that was also am impact with sigsegv issues.